How to add a subscript to lcm
I would like to write lcm (the lowest common multiple) with subscripted text as is done in this paper: 'On Chebyshev-Type Inequalities for Primes' by M. Nair. I also want to know how to write the less than or equal to as it is typeset here rather than using \leq.


Welcome to TeX.SX!

You can use the * form to declare a math operator taking limits

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*\lcm{lcm}

\begin{document}

\[
  d_n=\lcm_{1\leqslant m\leqslant n} \{m\}
\]

\end{document}


If you need gcd as well, you need to first "undefine" it
\let\gcd\relax
\DeclareMathOperator*{\gcd}{gcd}


Thank you so much @DavidCarlisle that works perfectly.

+1. You could also suggest \DeclareMathOperator*\lcm{\textsc{lcm}} to make the term look less than "1cm" ("one centimeter"). Also, LCM is an acronym and thus would benefit from being typeset using either uppercase or small-cap letters.

@Mico I have probably written lcm in hundreds of real documents and I have never used capitals or small caps, I think that would look really odd in English documents at least, other conventions may exist elsewhere of course.  I wouldn't consider lcm an acronym, it's a function just like log or sin it has some etymolygy behind the name of course, just as sin and log do, but it's just a name

Good points. Maybe I was thrown off a bit by the OP's use of a Times Roman font, in which "1" and "l" look very similar.
